# Unable to get JSON array using flicker API

Tags: android, json, api, flicker

I'm using Flicker API to display images. I'm getting the JSON Object from the API containing an array. But unable to parse it properly. When I'm trying to get the JSON array, it gives an exception:

> type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Below is my code snippet.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = DataParser.getDataFromWeb();

        try {
            if (jsonObject != null) {
                if (jsonObject.length() > 0) {
                    JSONArray array = null;
                    try {
                        array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("photos");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    int lenArray = array.length();
                    if (lenArray > 0) {
                        for (int jIndex = 0; jIndex < lenArray; jIndex++) {
                            //my codes
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {

            }
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            Log.i(DataParser.TAG, "" + je.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
```

The response I'm getting from the request is as follows:

```
{
  "photos": {
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 100,
    "perpage": 5,
    "total": 500,
    "photo": [
      {
        "id": "38935250244",
        "owner": "130108065@N08",
        "secret": "092b54d6be",
        "server": "4740",
        "farm": 5,
        "title": "misty.morning.rise.up",
        "ispublic": 1,
        "isfriend": 0,
        "isfamily": 0
      },
      {
        "id": "27869878289",
        "owner": "62440012@N04",
        "secret": "5e9929c4b1",
        "server": "4752",
        "farm": 5,
        "title": "Incoming",
        "ispublic": 1,
        "isfriend": 0,
        "isfamily": 0
      },
      {
        "id": "38942505174",
        "owner": "45571539@N06",
        "secret": "cbf3f74e37",
        "server": "4741",
        "farm": 5,
        "title": "Golden-eye",
        "ispublic": 1,
        "isfriend": 0,
        "isfamily": 0
      },
      {
        "id": "39656469601",
        "owner": "38945681@N07",
        "secret": "b470e84c18",
        "server": "4696",
        "farm": 5,
        "title": "New Year's Sunrise",
        "ispublic": 1,
        "isfriend": 0,
        "isfamily": 0
      },
      {
        "id": "25775783908",
        "owner": "100250163@N03",
        "secret": "a9dfe8ed85",
        "server": "4742",
        "farm": 5,
        "title": "Dissipate",
        "ispublic": 1,
        "isfriend": 0,
        "isfamily": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  "stat": "ok"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
        JSONObject jsonObject = DataParser.getDataFromWeb();
        try {
            if (jsonObject != null) {
                JSONObject phots= null;
                try {
                    phots = jsonObject.getJSONObject("photos");
                    JSONArray array = null;
                    try {
                        array = phots.getJSONArray("photo");
                        int lenArray = array.length();
                        if (lenArray > 0) {
                            for (int jIndex = 0; jIndex < lenArray; jIndex++) {
                                //my codes
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```